# itshidden.com VPN connection dies and will not reconnect on Ubuntu Server 10.04

Tags: vpn, pptp, ppp

I have a ubuntu server which should keep a connection to itshidden.com VPN through PPTP. Somehow, connection dies once in awhile and following lines appear in /var/log/syslog:

```
Jun 24 16:52:54 gbox-proxy20 pppd[613]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0xa4f1
Jun 24 16:52:54 gbox-proxy20 pppd[613]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0xa04a
Jun 24 16:52:54 gbox-proxy20 pppd[613]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0xe49a
Jun 24 16:52:54 gbox-proxy20 pppd[613]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0xed
Jun 24 16:52:54 gbox-proxy20 pppd[613]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0xf9
Jun 24 16:52:54 gbox-proxy20 pppd[613]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 'PPP Muxing' (0x59)
Jun 24 16:52:54 gbox-proxy20 pppd[613]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0x8b
Jun 24 16:52:54 gbox-proxy20 pppd[613]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0xec96
Jun 24 16:52:54 gbox-proxy20 pppd[613]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0x11
Jun 24 16:52:54 gbox-proxy20 pppd[613]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0xd64d
Jun 24 16:52:54 gbox-proxy20 pppd[613]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 'Stampede Bridging' (0x6f)
Jun 24 16:52:55 gbox-proxy20 pppd[613]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 'RTP IPHC Compressed non-TCP' (0x65)
Jun 24 16:52:55 gbox-proxy20 pppd[613]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0xb
Jun 24 16:52:55 gbox-proxy20 pppd[613]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0xc271
Jun 24 16:52:55 gbox-proxy20 pppd[613]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0x4817
Jun 24 16:52:55 gbox-proxy20 pppd[613]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0x9201
Jun 24 16:52:55 gbox-proxy20 pppd[613]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0x2e34
Jun 24 16:52:55 gbox-proxy20 pppd[613]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0x3
Jun 24 16:52:56 gbox-proxy20 pppd[613]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0xfa32
Jun 24 16:52:56 gbox-proxy20 pppd[613]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0x7c51
Jun 24 16:52:56 gbox-proxy20 pppd[613]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0x64c8
Jun 24 16:52:56 gbox-proxy20 pppd[613]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0x7
Jun 24 16:52:56 gbox-proxy20 pppd[613]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0xf2e5
Jun 24 16:52:56 gbox-proxy20 pppd[613]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 'Individual Link Encryption' (0x55)
Jun 24 16:52:56 gbox-proxy20 pppd[613]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0x9
Jun 24 16:52:56 gbox-proxy20 pppd[613]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0x407d
```

My  /etc/ppp/peers/itshidden file is:

```
pty "pptp vpn-pay.itshidden.com --nolaunchpppd"
name itshidden
remotename PPTP
require-mppe-128
require-mschap-v2
file /etc/ppp/options.pptp
ipparam itshidden
defaultroute
noipdefault
persist
maxfail 0
lcp-echo-failure 10
lcp-echo-interval 5
user "*********************"
```

Any suggestions?

Also, lcp-echo-failure/lcp-echo-interval parameters seem to not be working, since I don't see ppp resetting.